# How to delete all documents except most recent for each group in mongo? [SOLVED]

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection with this data registered

> {
> _id: 0000120210903, *iid*: **00001**, date: 20210903 }, {
> _id: 0000220210903, *iid*: 00002, date: 20210903 }, {
> _id: 0000120210101, *iid*: **00001**, date: 20210101 }

I want to delete all except the document with the most recent date for each *iid*.

My idea is to group by the date, select the _id of the register with the max(date) and then delete all except this array of _ids. But I can't figure out how to do it.

```
db.getCollection('testing_data').aggregate(
    { $sort:{ _id:1 }},
    { $group:{
         _id:"$iid",
         lastId:{ "$last":"$_id" },
    }},
    { $project:{ _id: 0, lastId: 1 } }
)
```

But I don't know where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[**Solution**]

To fix the problem I used an aggregation to recover the combination of the field *iid* (the identifier shared between documents) and the unique *_id* as an array.

Then for each element on the array it performs a deleteMany operation on the *iid* but letting out the most recent *_id*. In this case I sort by _id because it includes the date but could also sort by the field *date*.

Due to the high volume of data *{ allowDiskUse: true }* had to be put in the aggregate.

```
var ids = db.getCollection('testing_data').aggregate([
    { $sort:{ _id:1 }},
    { $group:{
         _id:"$iid",
         lastId:{ "$last":"$_id" },
    }},
    { $project:{ _id: 1, lastId: 1 } }
], { allowDiskUse: true } ).toArray();

ids.forEach(function(x){
    db.getCollection('testing_data').deleteMany({ "iid": x._id, "_id": {$ne:x.lastId} })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine Idea is just stock all `_id`s at some array that you want to delete, and then use `deleteMany` with `$or` filter

```js
db.getCollection("testing_data").find({}).toArray((err,data)=>{
  let to_elim = [];
  let filtering ={};
  for(let el of data){
    if(!filtering[el.iid]) filtering[el.iid] = el;
    else {
      if(filtering[el.iid].date>el.date) to_elim.push({_id:new ObjectID(el._id)})
    }
  }
  db.getCollection("testing_data").deleteMany({$or:to_elim})
})
```

I hope that all is written rightly, cause wrote all that down on mobile

There is missing some checking if something more recent...

Comment: Thanks! Your idea gave me the inspiration on how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

[**Solution**]

To fix the problem I used an aggregation to recover the combination of the field *iid* (the identifier shared between documents) and the unique *_id* as an array.

Then for each element on the array it performs a deleteMany operation on the iid but letting out the most recent *_id*. In this case I sort by *_id* because it includes the date but could also sort by the field date.

Due to the high volume of data { allowDiskUse: true } had to be put in the aggregate.

```
var ids = db.getCollection('testing_data').aggregate([
    { $sort:{ _id:1 }},
    { $group:{
         _id:"$iid",
         lastId:{ "$last":"$_id" },
    }},
    { $project:{ _id: 1, lastId: 1 } }
], { allowDiskUse: true } ).toArray();

ids.forEach(function(x){
    db.getCollection('testing_data').deleteMany({ "iid": x._id, "_id": {$ne:x.lastId} })
});
```